# Two rows in one in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The answer is too close, Thanks
But
The problem is that if too many records to be entered

```
           |    id   |    name   |    age    |   Tel
------------------------------------------
      1    |    1   |   Frank   |    40     |   null
      2    |    1   |   null    |    50     |   7834xx
      3    |    1   |   Alex    |    null   |   null
      4    |    1   |   null    |    20     |   null
      5    |    2   |   James   |    null   |   4121xx
```

Query return the Maximum value
Like:

```
           |    id   |   name    |    age    |   Tel
------------------------------------------
      1    |    1    |   Frank   |    50     |  7834xx
```

i need Select Query like this:

```
           |    id   |   name    |    age    |   Tel
------------------------------------------
      1    |    1    |   Alex    |    20     |  7834xx
```

what do I do? Plz?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: First try to save data in proper way. Aggregation will serve the purpose, but this is not solution,  the table itself is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a roundabout way to combine the last non-empty value of 3 columns:

```
-- Using a table variable for test data
declare @Test table (tableId int identity(1,1), id int, name varchar(100), age int, tel varchar(30));
insert into @Test (id, name, age, tel) values
(1,'Frank',40,null),
(1,null,50,'7834xx'),
(1,'Alex',null,null),
(1,null,20,null),
(2,'James',null,'4121xx');

select n.id, n.name, a.age, t.tel
from (
    select top(1) with ties id, name 
    from @Test 
    where name is not null
    order by row_number() over (partition by id order by tableId desc)
) n
inner join (
    select top(1) with ties id, age 
    from @Test 
    where age is not null
    order by row_number() over (partition by id order by tableId desc)
) a on (n.id = a.id)
inner join (
    select top(1) with ties id, tel 
    from @Test 
    where tel is not null
    order by row_number() over (partition by id order by tableId desc)
) t on (n.id = t.id);
```

or by re-using a CTE

```
;with CTE AS (
    select * ,
    row_number() over (partition by id, iif(name is not null,1,0) order by tableId desc) as rn_name,
    row_number() over (partition by id, iif(age is not null,1,0) order by tableId desc) as rn_age,
    row_number() over (partition by id, iif(tel is not null,1,0) order by tableId desc) as rn_tel
    from @Test
 )
select n.id, n.name, a.age, t.tel
from CTE n
join CTE a on (a.id = n.id and a.age is not null and a.rn_age = 1)
join CTE t on (t.id = n.id and t.tel is not null and t.rn_tel = 1)
where (n.name is not null and n.rn_name = 1);
```

Result :

```
╔════╦══════╦═════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name ║ age ║  tel   ║
╠════╬══════╬═════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ Alex ║  20 ║ 7834xx ║
╚════╩══════╩═════╩════════╝
```

After looking at this answer more than a year later.
You could also use the window function first_value for this.
Without using any join.

```
select Id, name, age, tel
from
(
    select Id
    , row_number() over (partition by id order by tableId desc) as rn
    , first_value(name) over (partition by id order by iif(name is null,1,0), tableId desc) as name
    , first_value(age) over (partition by id order by iif(age is null,1,0), tableId desc) as age
    , first_value(tel) over (partition by id order by iif(tel is null,1,0), tableId desc) as tel
    from @Test
) q
where rn = 1
and name is not null and age is not null and tel is not null;
```

Comment: @abdol-hamidHosseiny Thx. After looking at this more than I year later I realised that there was even a shorter solution. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to get max as below:

```
 Select Id, Max(name) as [Name], Max(age) as Age, Max(Tel) as Tel
 from yourtable
 Group by Id
```

Comment: What is that difference you are looking for?

Comment: i need last Record is null

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering and helping.
i find this query:

SELECT TOP 10
    (SELECT top(1) name FROM test1 where id=1 and name is not null order by autoID desc) as name
    ,(SELECT top(1) age FROM test1 where id=1 and age is not null order by autoID desc) as Age
,(SELECT top(1) Tel FROM test1 where id=1 and Tel is not null order by autoID desc) as Telephon
    FROM [dbo].[test1]
    group by id

its worked !!!
but i thing there are another Easy Way , maybe like this:

Select Id, NotNull(name) as [Name], NotNull(age) as Age, NotNull(Tel) as Tel
 from yourtable Group by Id

???